# type object '...' has no attribute 'objects'

Tags: python-3.x, django

In models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.db import models


class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

class Espresso(models.Model):
    employee = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user_esp_log")
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
    water_temp = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=1)
    water_TDS = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=ESPRESSO_TYPES, default= ESPRESSO_TYPES[0][1])
    batch_number = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    dry = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=2)
    wet = models.IntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Log added on {self.time} by {self.employee}"
```

In views.py the 'create_espresso' route attempts to create a new log as follows:

```
def create_espresso(request):
if request.method == "GET":
    return render(request, "score_sheet/espresso.html", {"form": Espresso()})
else:
    form = Espresso(request.POST)
    user = User.objects.get(username=request.user)

    if form.is_valid():
        espresso = form.save(commit=False)
        espresso.employee = user
        espresso.save()
        espressos = Espresso.objects.all()
        return render(request, "score_sheet/index.html", {
            "espressos": espressos,
            "message": "Log added"
        })
    else:
        return render(request, "score_sheet/espresso.html", {"form": form})
```

Also, here's the form POSTING to the view:

```
{% block body %}
<form action="{% url 'create_espresso' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_table }}
    <button class="btn btn-success">Log</button>
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

On submitting the form Django returns the following:
type object 'Espresso' has no attribute 'objects'

Here's the stacktrace in case it's needed:

```
Internal Server Error: /create_espresso
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
response = get_response(request)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site- 
packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py", line 21, in _wrapped_view
return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/Users/apostolospapas/coffee_log/coffeeLog/score_sheet/views.py", line 88, in 
create_espresso
espressos = Espresso.objects.all()
AttributeError: type object 'Espresso' has no attribute 'objects'
```

I'm confused as to what could be causing this.
Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Your model and form have the same name, `Espresso`. Change either and try again

Comment: You are using your `Espresso` model like a *form*, not a *model*. You should construct a `ModelForm` (for example `EspressoForm`), and use that to process data input.

Comment: Use filter in the queryset

Comment: Problem solved! Thank you very much for your help and kindness! Much appreciated!